# I have created a automation script to automate a task in web application. How to run the same script by 4 different user roles?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have created a automation script to automate a task in web application. But i want the same script to be run by 4 different user roles. How to do it? I'm using python language

I'm am a newbie.

Comment: What are the 4 different user roles?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run your script for the different users.

```py
import getpass

reader_id = input("Enter UserID for reader: ")
reader_pw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

author_id = input("Enter UserID for author: ")
author_pw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

admin_id = input("Enter UserID for admin: ")
admin_pw = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

...
```